# Google App Script Adding 180 days in a loop using if/else conditional statements

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

The problem I am trying to solve in Google Sheets is as follows:

add 180 days to whichever date passes my conditional test to every single row in a certain column based on 3 dates.

[Google Sheets Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwWuf.png)

I came up with the following script:

```html
function adjustDates() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  for(var i=2; i<5; i++) {

    var updatedCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 2).getDate;
    var removedCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 4).getDate;
    var implementedCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1).getDate;

    if (updatedCell == null && removedCell == null){
      activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue(implementedCell+180);
    } else if (updatedCell != null){
      activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue(updatedCell+180);
    } else {
      activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue(removedCell+180);
    }
  }
}
```

I think I nailed down the logic, but I can't figure out why I am getting #NUM! error in all of my rows. I don't need to worry about leap years so this was a brute force solution on my part.

I am very new to JavaScript so please be gentle.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about the sheets you're using but something doesn't seem right, not sure that you can add up "date" and "180" just like that.  In javascript you'd have to at least use ````date.setDate(date.getDate() + 180)````.  What's more is that javascript date will automatically handle the year for you, i.e. if you add 2 days to day 365, it will show the next year at day 2, perhaps your sheet is doing that for you.  However your #NUM! error is likely because of not being able to add "date" and 180 and it probably is returning a date and not a number.

Comment: There's no getDate method in Range Class.

Comment: Hey there, Just dropping a quick tip : you can use code fences with the js language identifer instead of snippets since the snippet feature here is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `getDate` in [class range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

You need to get the value first via `getValue`, and then as Matriarx mentioned, set the date using `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 180)`

```
var implementedCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

// we make sure to cast the date properly to avoid unexpected errors
var iCellDate = new Date(implementedCell);
iCellDate = iCellDate.setDate(iCellDate.getDate() + 180)
activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue(iCellDate);
```

Apply to all instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
    new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate() + 180)
```

Comment: In `if (date && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]')` the first test is redundant as any value that fails it will also fail the second test, and neither test catches an invalid date (i.e. a Date with a time value of NaN). :-)